# How to set Horizontal scrollbar to single select tag (dropdown)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set the horizontal scrollbar to the single select dropdown which has long text in its option text.
I tried it by adding div and setting the style , but it showing the scrollbar before popping the list..
How to set Horizontal scrollbar to single select tag (dropdown) ???

Answer (score 0):

you can give your selector box a fixed width to keep it smaller. but when clicking on it, there will be a scrollbar from your browser. if you want to change this, you need to create your own select box with javascript.

Oh and.. if you have that long select dropdowns, you're not really doing something which a user will like. Provide radio buttons or check boxes if you need to display a lot of text.

Comment: I m asking about Horizontal scrollbar in dropdaown, not vertical scrollbar. :)

Comment: you *can't* have a horizontal scrollbar in your select. that's what I'm saying.